# Is there a way to compile SASS to CSS without NodeJS?

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gulp

NodeJS is being restricted to be installed and we received a web work with a SASS file that I would like to continue working in that way. So I was hoping there could be other way to compile into CSS with all the same functionalities that Gulp has preferably.

Comment: if you are trying to converting manually, https://www.sassmeister.com/ would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can compile SASS without NodeJS.

First you have to install [Ruby](https://rubyinstaller.org/)
then have you use Sublime.? install SASS builder Plugin

then you can compile SASS to css.! with using cntrl + B for build

Below youtube link will explain clearly
https://youtu.be/ZDuQwzPgeMA

Comment: I am going to check this. Meanwhile, can Ruby be a replacement of Node also for compiling JS, like using Babel, minify, etc?

Comment: Could you please modify your answer and provide more information on how to use Ruby to compile into CSS?

Comment: I modified my answer. U can check it,!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can compile SCSS/SASS to CSS without using any Node Command.
With just one click you can compile SCSS/CSS to CSS.

**Follow these steps in Visual Studio Code Editor**

1. Click on the <kbd>Extensions</kbd> button on left side.
2. Then search "Live Sass Compiler" and install it.
3. Create a .scss file.
4. Then Press <kbd>Watch Sass</kbd> button at the bottom of the Editor,

This [Learnopidia article](https://learnopidia.com/how-to-compile-scss-to-css-without-nodejs-command/) will explain it in more details: